# Weird reducer redux hack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

So im just using redux to dispatch an action and am still adjusting to using the hooks (ive been working for some archaic projects;

I'm calling my action like this

```
function generalFunction2(data) { 
        return { 
            type: constants.ACTION, data 
          } 
      }

    const generalFunction1 = (data, action) => {
        dispatch(generalFunction2(data))
    }
```

So then in my actual reducer file im trying to use this code

```
xport function generalFunction(state = initialState, data) {
    const data = action.value;
    const { type, value } = data;
    switch (action.typr) {
        case constants.ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                [type]: value
              };
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

But i seem to be getting an undefined error on const type cannot be undefined.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

So instead im using this (what i consider a hack) anyone got any smarter/neater workarounds?

```
export function generalFunctionHack(state = initialState, data) {
    let type, value = "";
    if(action) {
        type = action.value.type;
        value = action.value.value;
    }
    switch (action.typr) {
        case constants.ACTION:
            return {
                ...state,
                [type]: value
              };
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
export function generalFunction(state = initialState, data) {
    const data = action.value; // you haven't defined action
    const { type, value } = data; // therefore data is undefined
    switch (action.typr) {}
}
```

Get eslint, learn how to use it well. It will eliminate errors like this.